# Question regarding the UK Governments new Eat Out Help Out scheme website

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-devtools

This is my first Stack Overflow question so thanks for your patience. The UK Government launches the new 'Eat Out Help Out' scheme on Monday and I was looking at the website to find local participating restaurants:

https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/eat-out-to-help-out/find-a-restaurant/

When you input and search for a valid postcode it redirects to a URL with a parameter of `'results?postcode=RM7+0FT'`, for example. However, when I look in Chrome's Dev Tools under Network I can't see any API calls.

I'm fairly new to programming but not so new that I wish I could figure this out. I'd quite like to play around with this data if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the API calls because the page is rendered [server-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction). You are redirected to a new page where all the data is fetched and populated on the server, so you only see the end result.

Comment: Thanks @nip for the response. I had a feeling it would be something like that, but was maybe hoping deep down I could access the data in some way. Thanks for your time!